# Rails: Get params from click

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a Pinterest-like app to learn Rails, where users can collect items and add them to collections.

I have an "Add to collection" button which opens a modal with a list of all collections of a user. This works fine on individual item show pages, but not on my item index page (which lists all items that have been posted).

This is my **collections controller**:

```
def index
    @item = Item.find(params[:item_id])

    @selected_collections = selected_collections(@item.id)
    @collections = current_user.collections

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {
        render
      }
    end
end
```

My **items controller**:

```
def index
    @items = Item.all.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
    @collections = current_user.collections
    @selected_collections = selected_collections(item.id)
end


def show
    @item = Item.find_by_id(params[:id])
    return render_not_found if @item.blank?
    @collections = current_user.collections
    @selected_collections = selected_collections(@item.id)
end
```

This is my **Add-to-collection button**, which should be shown for each item on the index:

```
<%= link_to "+ Add", item_collections_path(item, format: :js), class: 'btn btn-secondary btn-30', data: {toggle: 'modal', target: '#CollectionModal'}, remote: true, format: :js %>
```

And part of the **corresponding modal**:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <%= render 'collections/collections_list', :collections=>@collections, :selected_collections=>@selected_collections %>
  </div>
```

**_collection_list.html.erb**

```
<div id="collection_list">

<% @collections.each do |collection| %>
    <%= render 'collections/collection_checkbox', collection: collection, selected_collections: selected_collections %>
<% end %>

<%= render 'collections/collection_checkbox', collection: Collection.new, selected_collections: selected_collections %>

<div style='display: none;' class="new_collection_template">
    <%= render 'collections/collection_checkbox', collection: Collection.new, selected_collections: selected_collections %>
</div>
```

**_collection_checkbox.html.erb**

```
<div class="form-check">
```

" <%= 'checked' if selected_collections.include?(collection.id) %> <%= "disabled" unless collection.id %>>
    <%= collection.collection_name %>

```
<% if !collection.id %>
  <input type="text" class="collection-name" placeholder="New collection" />
<% end %>
```

On my index I get the following error message:
*undefined local variable or method `item' for
ItemsController:0x007f69022aefa0 Did you mean? item_url items_url item_path @items*

[Screenshot of Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmR1I.png)

I assume that this is because I don't have individual @item defined on my index. On the item show pages I can simply find the params in the URL. But how can I solve this problem on the index?

Thanks for your help, much appreciated :)

Comment: you missed '@' in item.id  `@selected_collections = selected_collections(item.id)`

Comment: The error is pretty self explainatory. You're querying the database for `@items` which will give a whole collection of items and using the local variable `item` which is not defined.

Comment: @Stephen: Thanks, but that doesn't solve the problem. It just gives me a NoMethod Error for 'id' because item is not defined.

Comment: @max: Exactly, so my question is how I can define item on the index page? Is that possible?

Comment: @julianx if you want to pass all of your items form your @items query, `selected_collections(@items.ids)` try like this

Comment: We have no idea what your selected_collections method does or how your assocations are setup and your code is pretty original so its impossible to guess. What you probally want is to query for the items where no association exists `Item.where.not(id: Item.joins(:collections).where(collection: { user: current_user }))` and then iterate through it.